# pandas - how to convert all columns from object to float type

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

I trying to convert all columns with '$' amount from object to float type.

With below code i couldnt remove the $ sign.

input:

```
df[:] = df[df.columns.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('$'))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `extract`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['$10.00','$10.00','$10.00']})
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float))
Out[333]: 
      A
0  10.0
1  10.0
2  10.0
```

Update

```
df.iloc[:,9:32]=df.iloc[:,9:32].apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float))
```

Comment: if i just want to apply from column number 9 to 32, how can i modify the code.

Comment: If I have decimals in the df, something like ['$10.40', '$10.05', '$10.80'] it ignores the digits after decimal.

Comment: @prabhakar then we do df.iloc[:,9:32]=df.iloc[:,9:32].replace({‘$’:’’},regex=True).astype(float)

Comment: Great, thank you. Just corrected small typos in your line around in replace, df.iloc[:,9:32]=df.iloc[:,9:32].replace({'\$':''},regex=True).astype(float)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below regular expression based matching to replace all occurrences of $ with null character

```
df = df.replace({'\$': ''}, regex=True)
```

UPDATE: As per @Wen suggestion, the solution will be

```
df.iloc[:,9:32]=df.iloc[:,9:32].replace({'\$':''},regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: add astype(float) also ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can also try using `applymap`:

```
df[:] = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x:  x.lstrip('$')).astype(float)
```

If `df` is:

```
   0   1   2
0  $1  7   5
1  $2  7   9
2  $3  7   9
```

Then, it will result in:

```
    0    1    2
0  1.0  7.0  5.0
1  2.0  7.0  9.0
2  3.0  7.0  9.0
```